# How to detect a (tight) loop in a binary?

Tags: assembly, binary, reverse-engineering, disassembly, objdump

How to detect (pattern matching) a (tight) loop in a binary objdump disassembly format on x86_64?

I think it would look like this:
an direct conditional jump to its previous address, that previous address and this conditional jump are the beginning and ending of this loop, respectively.

Comment: _"to its previous address"_. _Whose_ previous address?

Comment: Like `jl 0x555`,  `0x555` is its previous address. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Do you care if it's a loop that can also be entered in the middle by some random jump anywhere? That's the tricky part

Comment: You should detect if there is a conditional branch opcode going backwards. Unfortunately you can never know if it is effectively that, or if it is just data or pointers, so you're going to get a lot of false positives.

Comment: My main purpose is to find the potential most performance-cost loop in a binary. So if there a jump inside the loop, or somewhere else jumps in, does not make much difference.

Comment: ``or if it is just data or pointers''  why data or pointers would make a backwards branch?

Comment: You'll have to define your problem a lot better. You could have a tight loop where the conditional jump is a jump forward (think of a `while(true)` loop in C, with a conditional `break` somewhere in the middle). That's just one common variant. There are many non-obvious but not necessarily uncommon ways to write tight loops. You need to define which ones you want to identify. Otherwise your question is too broad to get anything like a reasonable answer.